# Will GC collect Activity reference if ViewModel holds interface reference which this Activity implements?

Tags: java, android, interface, garbage-collection, viewmodel

Suppose i have Activity A which implements interface I. My ViewModel class (VM) holds a reference on object which implements interface I:

```
class A extends Activity implements I{
  ...
  onCreate(){
    mViewModel.setI(this);
  }
}

class B extends ViewModel {
   private I iRef;
   ...
}
```

Will GC collect activity object if activity A destroys ? Or object will be ineligible for GC because of interface reference in ViewMode class ?

**update:**
In my project all VM stores in some VMHolder class to quickly assign it to view (activity), so VM object will not destroy when activity destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will GC collect activity object if activity A destroys ?

Yes ,As long as `I iRef` is not `static` and not being used in some thread , your activity and all objects in it will be eligible for garbage collection

> Object will be ineligible for GC because of interface reference in ViewMode
>   class ?

No , The life span of `mViewModel` object is shorter or depends upon the lifespan of the activity so when the activit's object dies , so does all the members of it,there will be no issue for garbage collection

Comment: In my project all VM stores in some VMHolder class to quickly assign it to view (activity), so VM object will not destroy when activity destroyed.

Comment: i don't get the idea what actually you are trying to achieve here with view holder and view model and what your `VMHolder` is doing but as long as no static reference is used and no threading is used to update viewmodel , it's unlikely to see a memory leak plus you can take help of [some inbuild tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html)